# Multiple Taylor diagram in one Figure in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, facet-wrap, plotrix

I am trying to plot `taylor diagram` for each `data.frame` `(i.e., Precipitation, Max_Temp, and Min_temp)` on same `figure`. Each `data.frame` have a `ref observation` and `model outputs` represented by `(A1,G2, and G3)`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotrix)

set.seed(123)

precipitation <- data.frame(Ref = runif(730,1,5), A1 = runif(730,0,8), G2 = runif(730,2,6), G3 = runif(730,1,7)) 
Max_Temp <-  data.frame(Ref = runif(730,-5,30), A1 = runif(730,-8,32), G2 = runif(730,-2,28), G3 = runif(730,-10,25))
Min_Temp <-  data.frame(Ref = runif(730,-20,5), A1 = runif(730,-25,10), G2 = runif(730,-25,6), G3 = runif(730,-15,10))
```

I tried the code to just draw the diagram for precipitation but am getting error.

```
precipitation %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Models", values_to = "values", -Ref) %>% 
  taylor.diagram(Ref, values, col = Models)
```

I would like to have a Figure like below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your sample data will produce a plot like you expect, but you could try filtering your dataframe for each model and overlay the points on the same plot with the `add = TRUE` option. Also, I think the [explosion pipe](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/exposition.html) will help (`%$%`), and I just learned it's actually called the 'exposition pipe' in the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotrix)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(123)
precipitation <- data.frame(Ref = runif(730,1,5), A1 = runif(730,0,8), G2 = runif(730,2,6), G3 = runif(730,1,7)) 
Max_Temp <-  data.frame(Ref = runif(730,-5,30), A1 = runif(730,-8,32), G2 = runif(730,-2,28), G3 = runif(730,-10,25))
Min_Temp <-  data.frame(Ref = runif(730,-20,5), A1 = runif(730,-25,10), G2 = runif(730,-25,6), G3 = runif(730,-15,10))

precipitation %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Models", values_to = "values", -Ref) %>% 
  filter(Models == "A1") %$%
  taylor.diagram(Ref, values, col = "blue", pch = 1)

precipitation %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Models", values_to = "values", -Ref) %>% 
  filter(Models == "G2") %$%
  taylor.diagram(Ref, values, col = "red", pch = 2, add = TRUE)

precipitation %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Models", values_to = "values", -Ref) %>% 
  filter(Models == "G3") %$%
  taylor.diagram(Ref, values, col = "green", pch = 3, add = TRUE)
```

[image: example_2.png]